# How do I obtain a DC.js file for versions greater than 4.0?

Tags: dc.js

I'd like to upgrade from DC.js v4.0.0 to v4.2.7, since [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1882#issuecomment-1832911949) indicates that 4.2.7 is a stable release.  The GitHub page has a "Releases" pane on the right-hand side that I was previously able to get the library file from.  It lists 4.0 as the latest release, however, and has nothing more recent than that.

In the GitHub fileset itself I can switch to the 4.2.7 tag, but I can't find any file suitable for inclusion in a web page the way I typically can, it this case a file with a name of the form `dc.js` or `dc.min.js`.

How do I get the file `dc.js`/`dc.min.js` for version 4.2.7?